# how to pass table values to next php page when form is submitted

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to access the table values to inventory_issue, but I'm unable to do it....
        I'm able to just get the value  of checkbox but not the others.
        Can anyone help me with this..?

```
if($select=='soldering_wire') {
?>
<!-- <form class="push_1" id="inventory2"  action="inventory_issue.php" method="post" onSubmit="return false;"> -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Batch Number</th>
            <th>Gauge</th>
            <th>Check to Approve</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `$select`";
        //echo $sql;
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr class=". "gradeX>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
   ?>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"> </td>

    <?php
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>

    </table>

    <?php } ?>

    <button id="sub" class="form-control btn btn-primary"onClick="aj2();">Issue</button>
    <span id="result2"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: don't you getting your values in `$_POST`?what problem you are facing?

Comment: You can't get the info on the next page when your data is just in a **TD**, just store the table-id to the checkbox, and retrieve the values again on the next page?

Comment: I want the values of **TD** on the next page... @Naruto can u give me any exmaple

Comment: you can get by giving them name attribute.

Comment: Just store the value in Hidden tag and access it from next page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get post values of <td></td> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392722/how-to-get-post-values-of-td-td-tags)

Comment: If you want values on the next page, then use $_GET request on page load else store into session and then get.Don't try to use javascript.